# With the Android 4.2 camera app, how can I tell if I have a GPS lock?

Tags: camera, 4.2-jelly-bean, geotagging

My Galaxy Nexus has just been updated to v4.2 of Jellybean, Google seem to have totally changed the camera app in this update and there's a few functions that I just can't find.

As I'm travelling a lot at the moment, I like to make sure that most of my pictures are geo-tagged so that I can work out where I was and when later! As I'm not in my home country, I have data disabled to save on extortionate roaming charges, so most of the GPS-Assistance functions don't work and GPS locks take longer than normal.

Previous versions of the Android camera app have had a small icon near the top of the screen in the camera app that flashes to indicate that the GPS is searching for a lock, that then turns solid when a good GPS lock is achieved. There doesn't seem to be any similar icon in the built-in camera app in the stock GED version of 4.2.

Is there any way that I can tell if the camera has achieved a GPS lock before I take a picture?

Comment: Is this you? http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2000943

Comment: @TheAndroNerd nope not me, but that is the exact same problem with no answer, I'll keep an eye on that thread too, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press the right soft-key (switch application soft-key). The application switcher in Android 4.2 includes the notification bar, which shows if there´s a GPS fix. You can press the right soft-key again to return to the camera app.

Comment: Strangely the GPS icon only appears as I switch back to the camera, so you have to be quite quick at spotting it. Bit of a kludgey workaround, but it does seem to work, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This has been left out of the 4.2 Camera application.

You could get around this, if you really wanted the icon back, by installing the old camera app. You would need to be rooted to do this. You could also install a custom camera app off Google Play, which will not require you to be rooted.

Comment: I just checked on my smartphone: Android 4.2.1 camera still lacks GPS lock indicator.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your camera app and send it to background.
2. Then use this free app, [GPS Test](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chartcross.gpstest), to search for a GPS lock.
3. Once you acquire a GPS lock (yellow indicator on *GPS Status* section turns green), bring to front the camera and take the photo.

[image: GPS lock acquired in GPS Test app]

Answer (score -2):

When you open your camera, touch the "setting" widget that shows up by default on the right hand side.  The bottom choice looks like three sliders, that's your settings.  One of the choices is "store location."  That enables and disables geotagging.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Geotagging is already enabled, and the questioner is trying to tell whether GPS has fixed the position yet.