# When taking pictures with GPS enabled, is the 'has the "GPS searching/locked notification icon" been disabled?

Tags: gps, camera, 4.3-jelly-bean, geotagging

Background:

In stock (i.e. pure Google with no manufacturer customizations) Android 4.3 using the built-in camera app, I am using the geotagging feature of the camera app.

Description of the problem:

When the geotagging is turned on I don't see any GPS status in the notification bar. Previously when in the camera app on older version when geotagging is turned on I would see an icon appear in the notifcation bar. The icon that appears would indicate your GPS model is in use and a circle would indicate 'searching for GPS' and then the filled in circle would indicate 'GPS acquired and locked'.

Question:

**When you enable geotagging in Android 4.3 built-in camera app, has the 'GPS searching/locked notification icon' been hidden even though GPS is being used?**

Motivation:

The reason I ask is because the previous method is akin to a video camera's red blinking light . Where the red blinking light tells you that you are recording and then you can take appropriate action. Without the red blinking light on the video camera you would have all sorts of recordings when you didn't want and other problematic scenarios.

Returning back to the Android camera app scenario, if the GPS icon doesn't ever appear to the user... even if GPS is actively being used --> that would lead to situations where I would record the GPS location for a photo when I didn't want to record the GPS location.

Comment: re - "I saw the GPS notification show up for about 1 second": I also have a Nexus 4. I did the exact same thing and did not see the GPS icon show up at all for all my geotagged pictures. I went to the gallery and confirmed that the pictures were geotagged by checking the 'details' of the picture and seeing a lat/long. / I have all location services enabled (i.e. access to my locaiton is on, gps checked, wifi and mobile network location checked). I tried disabling wife and mobile network location. I still did not get any GPS icon to show.

Comment: Did you use the stock camera app in 4.2? That didn't show the lock icon either: [With the Android 4.2 camera app, how can I tell if I have a GPS lock?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34315/)

Comment: @GAThrawn ahh good catch on the duplicate question. I am using the stock camera app. I observed the same behavior as seen in the question you linked to. Specifically [this comment "Strangely the GPS icon only appears as I switch back to the camera, so you have to be quite quick at spotting it. Bit of a kludgey workaround, but it does seem to work, thanks."](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34315/with-the-android-4-2-camera-app-how-can-i-tell-if-i-have-a-gps-lock#comment45054_34722)

Comment: I saw this topic recently in another forum. Only some devices seem to be affected; and there are some apps one could use to force the GPS revealing its state AFAIR.

Answer (score 2):

I've just tried on my Nexus 4 and it does show up, although very very briefly.

I had GPS turned on, took a photo and quickly opened the app switching 'menu'. I saw the GPS notification show up for about 1 second and then it disappeared. I guess this is because it quickly grabs your location and stores that with the image, and then "doesn't care" where you are so doesn't access your GPS location again until you take another picture.